# Using panels3, how can I output a mutivalue cck field using tokens?

Tags: drupal, cck, keyword, token, drupal-panels

In my website, I have a custom content type called "projects". This type as a User Reference Field called "Project Author(s)" and another user Reference Field called "Project Supervisor(s)". These fields are mutivalue fields (can have 1 to unlimited values) and belong to a FieldGroup called "Project Info".

I also have installed the Content Profile Module, which enables me to add cck fields to user profile pages. So, I added two Custom Fields to user profile content type called "First name" and "Last Name".

Using panels3, I created a custom content pane with a table (code below)

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="100px"><strong>Author(s)</strong>
    </td>
    <td>%node:field_project_authors-link</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Supervisor(s)</strong></td>
    <td>%node:field_project_supervisors-link</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Cooperation</strong></td>
    <td>%node:field_project_coop-link</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Problem: Although %node:field_project_authors, %node:field_project_supervisors and %node:field_project_coop are muti value fields, only the first item (delta) is shown.For instance, if Project A has 2 authors (john and marie) only john is shown.
Same happens when I try to show user's first name and last name instead of %node:field_project_authors. Only the first author's names are shown. (I'm using author's user reference as relationship)

**Question: How can I show all values (deltas) of a mutivalue cck field?**

Side-notes:
1)In my first approach, I used views2 to pull authors and supervisors from the database and then add them to panels but I had a lot of issues regarding formatting and duplicated information that I couldn't really address.< br />
2) I'm open to any suggestions that you think might solve this issue. I'm even open to hardcode it in PHP if you can point me in the right dirrection (i'm pretty new to Srupal so...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, only way I could achieve this was with PHP by acessing the $node object.